# Installing Python 3.12.1

Tags: python, windows

[The option of **Use admin privileges when installing py.exe**Due to which the installation error is occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyiIU.jpg)

I was tring to install Python.But there's a problem in the installation.
I've followed all the same steps as given on the website for installation,still the error is there and the screen that has appeared for installation is abit different as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is the error?

Comment: what problem do you get? We can't see your computer, and we can't read in your mind - so you have to add all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: BTW: version 3.12 is very new version and some modules may not work with this version - so sometimes it is better to use older 3.11 and wait few months.

Answer (score 2):

Its kinda obvious, but have you tried to run it as
[admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIzyD.png) ?